# What happened to my trees?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the deal with trees in minecraft? Ever since the update they've been.. er... three-toned.
[image]

Is this intentional behavior?

Comment: Same here. I'm wondering if it's supposed to be like that, or if it's an minor error from Notch adding the other tree types.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't know mushrooms could grow *on* leaves like that. That's pretty neat.

Comment: According to the wikia: "It is possible for a tree to be generated with different colored leaves. This may be a bug." I didn't think this was helpful enough to be an answer, but it is some information I guess.

Comment: These trees weren't generated post patch though -- it's a world pre 1.2.

Comment: Seems like just little changes from the recent update

Comment: Yes, but *why*?

Comment: Hey, at least it looks cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is a bug upon the save moving to the newer version of Minecraft.
[image]

I made a new world, and all the trees were generated with the same colour of leaves. Because of this, I'm almost certain the multicoloured trees were unintentional.

Comment: the tree colours are intentional turn to fancy graphics and that birch will be a different colour